# create_pretraining_data.py is writing 0 records to tf_examples.tfrecord while training custom BERT model

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model, google-natural-language

I am writing a custom BERT model on my own corpus, I generated the vocab file using BertWordPieceTokenizer and then running below code

```
!python create_pretraining_data.py
--input_file=/content/drive/My Drive/internet_archive_scifi_v3.txt
--output_file=/content/sample_data/tf_examples.tfrecord
--vocab_file=/content/sample_data/sifi_13sep-vocab.txt
--do_lower_case=True
--max_seq_length=128
--max_predictions_per_seq=20
--masked_lm_prob=0.15
--random_seed=12345
--dupe_factor=5
```

Getting output as :

`INFO:tensorflow:*** Reading from input files ***`

`INFO:tensorflow:*** Writing to output files ***`

`INFO:tensorflow: /content/sample_data/tf_examples.tfrecord`

`INFO:tensorflow:Wrote 0 total instances`

Not sure why I am always getting 0 instances in `tf_examples.tfrecord`, what am I doing wrong?

I am using `TF version 1.12`
FYI..generated vocab file is 290 KB.

Answer (score 0):

It can not read the input file, please use `My\ Drive` instead of `My Drive`:

```
--input_file=/content/drive/My\ Drive/internet_archive_scifi_v3.txt
```